# Strongly typed dataset using variables for column names

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, strong-typing

I am currently referencing a generic DataSet via an index and would like to convert this to a strongly-typed DataSet of the table type.  The issue is that my index to the DataRow is a variable.

Currently I am doing the following where the History_Column value is pulled from the database.

`e.Dr[c.History_Column.ToString()] = Entry;`

I would like to define the DataRow ('Dr' in the example) as a type of the table so I can do something similar to the following:

`e.Dr.COLUMN_NAME = Entry;`

How can I use dynamic variables in this fashion?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want strongly-typed, or do you want dynamic? Two totally different ways to handle it.

Comment: I need to have it operate dynamically but I am having a problem with the TableAdapter Update().  It is telling me that the row already exists despite having assigned new values to the columns.  The primary key hasn't changed so I thought the point was that the changed would be recognized and the database UPDATE command would execute?  Is this not working due to my "dynamic" creation and having lost the strongly-typed nature of the DataSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dynamic type to get you part of the way there, but your goal sounds kind of contradictory.

```
dynamic Dr = new ExpandoObject();
Dr.whatever = 6;
Dr.anything = "asdf";
```

If you use `ExpandoObject` with `dynamic`, you can assign any property.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be, then, is it possible to use a dynamic index as I'm trying to do and still be able to do something like this DataTable.Rows.Add(Dr) and then TableAdapter.Update(DataTable)?  In this case I have the DataTable and TableAdapter created from the strongly-typed DataSet creation.

Answer (score 0):

A strongly-typed dataset is a class in your application that derives from the built-in dataset class.  You have to add them to your project in visual studio.  Here are some directions for [creating strongly typed datasets](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714).

However, I suggest that you take the opportunity to refactor and get away from datasets altogether (if you can).  [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx) provides strongly typed property accessors for each column, a better "unit-of-work" pattern, a graphical database mapping tool, and it is much easier to use.

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to take the time to refactor my application since I realized there are other "better" options but I don't currently have the time to do this and is not currently supported at my corporation.  I will keep this in mind for the future, though.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.